# Entity Framework query to return list with simple filter

Tags: .net-core, razor-pages, entity-framework-core-3.1

Is there a simple way to modify this code to return only records where *LocationID* matches the id I'm trying to pass as a parameter? Needless to say, this doesn't compile. I thought Entity Framework was meant to make things easier, but I've searched online and can't find an understandable example of how to assign a simple query where a field in a single table/entity matches a number.

```
public async Task<List<PC>> GetPCsAsync(int id)
{
   // Get our data. Don't yet know how to feed the variable to EF/Linq
   PCList = await (from p in db.PC 
   select new PC {p.LocationID = id}).ToListAsync();
   return PCList;
}
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

And also if you want to do it using Query Syntax it would be something like this:

```
PCList = await (from p in db.PC 
                where p.LocationID == id
                select p).ToListAsync();
```

Here's a [link](http://dotnetpattern.com/linq-query-method-syntax) to understand the differences between Query and Method syntax.

Comment: Thanks. I'll give this a try today.

Comment: Thanks again. This worked when I fed it a literal parameter. However, when I tried to pass the parameter using Model.OurLoc (for "id") I got no output. That's something I as an incompetent programmer will have to try to figure out - I just don't seem to get the very rigid way scope works in .Net Core.

Answer (score 1):

```
var list = db.PC.Where(x=>x.LocationID == id).ToList();
```

for async

```
var listAsync = await db.PC.Where(x=>x.LocationID == id).ToListAsync();
```

I hope it's help you!

Comment: Many thanks. I've just logged on again and it's 11pm here in the UK so I'll give these a try tomorrow.